# Using Geographic Transformation in Projection?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I copied my coordinate files into Coordinate folder inside `Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Esri\Desktop 10.2\ArcMap\Coordinate Systems\....`

The problem arises when I try to project using a custom made Geographic Transformation. When I select the Output Coordinate then in Geographic Transformation (optional) there comes nothing.

Where are the transformation parameters created?

Amazingly, this only happened in one of my laptop. Otherwise, this was not the problem before.

Answer (score 1):

If you are defining a custom transformation - it is typically stored in the folder
`%USER%\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.3\ArcToolbox\CustomTransformations`

Transformations are defined using a GTF file.  If there are extra resources required for the transformation (such as NTv2 files) they will be typically stored in the ArcMap installation folder (e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\pedata)

Reference:  [ESRI Create Custom Geographic Transformation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-custom-geographic-transformation.htm)

Comment: Thanks for replying. PRJ file is copied from another source, it was not created in the particular computer. So, Custom Transformations folder is blank. Also, there is not any GTF file in the mentioned NTv2 folder. What might be the solution then?

Comment: GTF files are stored in the CustomTransformations folder on your user account (not the pedata folder). I would recommend acquiring the GTF from the same place you sourced the PRJ.  Otherwise you can create the transformation from scratch if you know all the parameters.

Comment: As I mentioned, Custom Transformations folder of my user account is blank. I just copied the PRJ files from other source, i do not know the parameters. Anyways, thank you.

Comment: I recommend starting a new question detailing your CRS (i.e. contents of the PRJ file) and seeing if anyone knows details of the transformation you require.